# Telekrik SideDrawer issue - Cannot read property ‘showDrawer’ of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, telerik, nativescript

I was implementing Telerik's SideDrawer component and got a error **JS: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'showDrawer' of undefined**.
I am using this tutorial 
https://www.nativescript.org/blog/a-deep-dive-into-telerik-ui-for-nativescripts-sidedrawer

My XML is ,

```
<Page xmlns:lv="nativescript-telerik-ui/listview" xmlns:sd="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer" loaded="pageLoaded" unloaded="pageUnloaded" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatedTo="onNavigatedTo">            <ActionBar title="RadSideDrawer Demo" class="action-bar" >
    <ActionItem tap="toggleDrawer" ios.systemIcon="4" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_btn_add" ios.position="left" />
</ActionBar>
        <sd:RadSideDrawer id="sideDrawer" drawerLocation="Left">    
            <!-- side drawer content -->
            <sd:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
                <StackLayout class="sidedrawer-left">
                    <StackLayout class="sidedrawer-header">
                        <Label text="Hello RadSideDrawer!" class="sidedrawer-header-brand" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout class="sidedrawer-content">
                        <Label text="Home" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
                        <Label text="Basics" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
                        <Label text="Options" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
                        <Label text="Help" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
                        <Label text="Advanced" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </sd:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>

            <!-- The main content -->


        </sd:RadSideDrawer>
```

and javascript file is

```
var view = require("ui/core/view");
var drawer="";
exports.toggleDrawer = function() {

    drawer.showDrawer();
};
exports.onNavigatedTo = function() {
    drawer = view.getViewById(page, "sideDrawer");
};
```

Using Latest version tns-android,tns-core-mocules,telekriki-ui...
What am I missing? Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: I think you should review basic NS programming - take a look at some samples etc. For example, like how to access the current page from within onNavigatedTo().

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem; it did not happen in previous versions; it works well on ios; only android is having trouble.
If the first time is executed, there is no error, and sidedrawer has the value.
But in the second run, it returns an error and returns "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a reference to the page before doing getViewById()

so your onNavigatingTo will look like

```
exports.onNavigatedTo = function(args) {
    const page = args.object;
    drawer = page.getViewById(page, "sideDrawer");
};
```